# python (scipy): Resizing a sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm having trouble resizing a matrix - the `set_shape` function seems to
have no effect:

```
>>> M
<14x3562 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float32'>'
   with 6136 stored elements in LInked List format>
>>> new_shape = (15,3562)
>>> M.set_shape(new_shape)
>>> M
<14x3562 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float32'>'
   with 6136 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

Anyone else come across this?

I also tried doing this by hand, i.e.

```
>>> M._shape = new_shape
>>> M.data = np.concatenate(M.data, np.empty((0,0), dtype=np.float32))
```

but that throws up an error:

```
*** TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

or

```
>>> M.data = np.concatenate(M.data, [])
*** TypeError: an integer is required
```

For info:

- Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41)
- scipy 0.11.0.dev-03f9e4a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to add a row of zeros at the end:

```
>>> M = sp.lil_matrix((14, 3562))
>>> sp.vstack([M, sp.lil_matrix((1, 3562))])
<15x3562 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: Weirdly that gives me an error: `row = sparse.lil_matrix((1,3562))` followed by `sparse.vstack(M, row)` gives  `*** NotImplementedError: adding a scalar to a CSC or CSR matrix is not supported`

Comment: and before you ask M is definitely a lil matrix!

Comment: @tdc: that's `sparse.vstack([M, row])`.

Comment: genius, thanks. I've been shaving yaks all afternooon with this one!!