# Looping over large sparse array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Let's say I have a (sparse) matrix `M` size `(N*N, N*N)`. I want to select elements from this matrix where the outer product of `grid` (a `(n,m)` array, where `n*m=N`) is True (it is a boolean 2D array, and `na=grid.sum()`). This can be done as follows

```
result = M[np.outer( grid.flatten(),grid.flatten() )].reshape (( N, N ) )
```

`result` is an `(na,na)` sparse array (and `na < N`). The previous line is what I want to achieve: get the elements of M that are true from the product of `grid`, and squeeze the ones that aren't true out of the array.

As `n` and `m` (and hence `N`) grow, and `M` and `result` are sparse matrices, I am not able to do this efficiently in terms of memory or speed. Closest I have tried is:

```
result = sp.lil_matrix ( (1, N*N), dtype=np.float32 )
# Calculate outer product
A = np.einsum("i,j", grid.flatten(), grid.flatten())  
cntr = 0
it = np.nditer ( A, flags=['multi_index'] )
while not it.finished:
    if it[0]:
        result[0,cntr] = M[it.multi_index[0], it.multi_index[1]]
        cntr += 1
# reshape result to be a N*N sparse matrix
```

The last reshape could be done by [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511879/reshape-sparse-matrix-efficiently-python-scipy-0-12), but I haven't got there yet, as the while loop is taking forever.

I have also tried selecting nonzero elements of A too, and looping over but this eats up all of the memory:

```
A=np.einsum("i,j", grid.flatten(), grid.flatten())  
nzero = A.nonzero() # This eats lots of memory
cntr = 0
for (i,j) in zip (*nzero):
    temp_mat[0,cntr] = M[i,j]
    cnt += 1
```

'n' and 'm' in the example above are around 300.

Comment: I added `sparse` to the title because indexing speeds are slower than for regular `numpy` arrays.

Comment: While `lil` is best for indexed assignment and lookup, it is usually better to manipulate the `coo` style of input arrays directly, and build the sparse matrix after.  Look at `sparse.bmat` to see how `sparse` ifself uses the `coo` format to construct a complex matrix.

Comment: Even with `N=4`, your `it` iteration takes for ever - literally.  You are missing a `next(it)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was a typo, or code error, but your example is missing an `iternext`:

```
R=[]
it = np.nditer ( A, flags=['multi_index'] )
while not it.finished:
    if it[0]:
        R.append(M[it.multi_index])
    it.iternext()
```

I think appending to a list is simpler and faster than `R[ctnr]=...`.  It's competitive if `R` is a regular array, and sparse indexing is slower (even the fastest `lil` format).

`ndindex` wraps this use of a nditer as:

```
R=[]
for index in np.ndindex(A.shape):
    if A[index]:
        R.append(M[index])
```

`ndenumerate` also works:

```
R = []
for index,a in np.ndenumerate(A):
   if a:
       R.append(M[index])
```

But I wonder if you really want to advance the `cntr` each `it` step, not just the `True` cases.  Otherwise reshaping `result` to `(N,N)` doesn't make much sense.  But in that case, isn't your problem just

```
M[:N, :N].multiply(A)
```

or if `M` was a dense array:

```
M[:N, :N]*A
```

In fact if both `M` and `A` are sparse, then the `.data` attribute of that `multiply` will be the same as the `R` list.

```
In [76]: N=4
In [77]: M=np.arange(N*N*N*N).reshape(N*N,N*N)
In [80]: a=np.array([0,1,0,1])
In [81]: A=np.einsum('i,j',a,a)
In [82]: A
Out[82]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])

In [83]: M[:N, :N]*A
Out[83]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 17,  0, 19],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 49,  0, 51]])

In [84]: c=sparse.csr_matrix(M)[:N,:N].multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(A))
In [85]: c.data
Out[85]: array([17, 19, 49, 51], dtype=int32)

In [89]: [M[index] for index, a in np.ndenumerate(A) if a]
Out[89]: [17, 19, 49, 51]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I didn't quite explain properly what I needed, but it's replicating the top line of code. I have changed the question to reflect this. I'm pretty sure my attempts don't solve my problem very well...